# How can I resize everything in xubuntu?

Tags: xubuntu, launcher

Now I've installed xubuntu-desktop on ubuntu, I can't find a way to resize the top bar. What should I do to resize every single icon and the text in the bar on the top?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described [here](http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-panel/preferences):

> The panel preferences can be opened by going to Settings → Panel in
>   your applications menu. You can also access panel preferences by right
>   clicking on your panel and going to Panel Settings. If you right click
>   on space occupied by a panel plugin, you can access panel preferences
>   by going to Panel → Panel Preferences....

So, you may follow this brief guide to enter xfce4 panel settings, find there tab "Display" and using "Measurements" options resize your panel.